# Java GC Logs not getting created

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to generate the GC logs for one of my Java processes and I have set the VM arguments in the shell script as follows:

```
export QUOTE_SERVER_CONFIG=~/conf/config.cfg
source ${QUOTE_SERVER_CONFIG}

jvmargs="-verbose:gc -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCCause -Xloggc:\"${LOGS_DIR}/QSGC202100331.log\""
java -cp ${LIB_DIR}/MyJar.jar:${LIB_DIR}/* com.ravi.MainClass ${HOME_STR}
```

And this is how my config.cfg file looks like

```
####################
## PATH VARIABLES ##
####################
export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/root/bin"
export HOME=~
export HOME_STR="${HOME}/fxstr"
export SCRIPT_DIR="${HOME_STR}/bin"
export LIB_DIR="${HOME_STR}/lib"
export LOGS_DIR="${HOME_STR}/logs/"
```

However, I am unable to see any GC file getting created when I run the shell script. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not pass `jvmargs` to `java`.

Try `java ${jvmargs} -cp ${LIB_DIR}/MyJar.jar:${LIB_DIR}/* com.ravi.MainClass ${HOME_STR}`

Comment: talex, thanks for the update. Now I see that the application is not coming up due to this error.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid file name for use with -Xloggc: Filename can only contain the characters [A-Z][a-z][0-9]-_.%[p|t] but it has been "/home/ravi/logs/QSGC202100331.log"
Note %p or %t can only be used once

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support path, only file name.

Comment: talex, thanks again. I tried specifying just the file name and it seem to have generated the file now. However, the file is being generated in the same folder as that of the .sh file. I need to figure out how to change the file path. Any hints please?

Comment: I was wrong here quote from doc "The -Xloggc parameter does not allow quotes around the defined path. Otherwise, it will throw the "Invalid file name for use with -Xloggc" error.
"

Comment: Use `-Xloggc:${LOGS_DIR}/QSGC202100331.log`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick assistance talex